# JQuery - get page?

Tags: jquery

I nearly have this going but don't have sufficient brain power to work out the final step.

This is what happens at the moment.

1) Page loads
2) When a link is clicked, a hash is added to the url with the page id. This is saved to the browser history.

I have the Ajax call set up, if I attach it to the link function it works fine. The problem is getting the id from the url. Here is what I have.

```
var id = urlToId(window.location);
if (id != undefined) {
    go(id);
}

function urlToId(url) { alert(url);
    var segments = url.split('#'); alert(segments);
    var id = segments[1];
    return id;
}
```

alert(url) = http://localhost/site/index.php?p=1#1
-- Javascript Error: url.split is not a function.

I sense that if I can just get rid of the JavaScript error I should be golden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function urlToId() {
    return window.location.hash.substr(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url parameter refers to the window.location object which does not have a split function (it is not a string).

Try `window.location.hash` instead, this will return just from the # onwards as a string. Rather than the window.location object.

```
var id = hashToId(window.location.hash); 
if (id != undefined) { 
    go(id); 
} 

function hashToId(hash) {
    return hash.slice(1); // remove the leading #
}
```